# VBA Function #VALUE and debugging disabled

Tags: vba, function, debugging

Every time I try to put some arguments in a Function Excel would return #VALUE. Below is one of the examples. Also, I cannot debug when I put arguments in. What is the possible cause? Thank you.

```
Function lastrowC(SelectedCell As Range)
    sc = SelcetedCell.Column
    lastrowC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, sc).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work due to a typo. If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code, then try to calculate, VBA will
show you the problem (you misspelled **Selected**)

Either way, please consider the below code which will target the correct worksheet rather the active worksheet. Your code, as is, will likely look to the wrong sheet to determine the last row under certain circumstances. You need to look at the sheet where the range was selected, which is not always going to be the same as the active sheet

Paste the below code in a `Module` to call function from excel

---

```
Function lastrowC(Target As Range) As Long

With Target.Worksheet
    lastrowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
End With

End Function
```

Comment: It was in a Module before. I merged your code with mine. And all I did was changing "my" SelectedCell with "your" Target and it works now. I wonder why this code now works?

   `Function lastrowCd(Target As Range) As Integer
    sc = Target.Column
    lastrowCd = Cells(Rows.Count, sc).End(xlUp).Row
    End Function`